# Jio recharge - payment cannot be processed error

Tags: india, cellphones, payment-cards, mobile-operators

I am in India and I am trying to renew my 4G subscription with Jio. When doing so, I get the error "Payment failure - Your request for recharge cannot be processed at this time. Please try after some time" (see screenshot below). I get the error both using the app and using the website.

I started trying 24h ago, and I keep getting the same error message. Is there a way to go around it? I have two mastercards issued by European banks (Unicredit and N26).

[image]

Comment: What is a Jio account? Do they have a Help team you can contact?

Comment: Maybe try with a local Indian payment instrument.

Comment: @Traveller Jio is an national mobile service/cellular provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs in the MyJio app, try to recharge using the Jio website through an internet browser.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way would be to go to a local street shop that works with Jio, pay in cash and have them renew/reload your account.

Shops should be easy to identify: you'll see their advertisement/billboard on shops that deal with them

Answer (score 1):

Foreign credit cards may not usually work for online cellular recharges. I tried with my Singapore credit card and was getting a similar failure. Switched to an Indian card and went fine.

You can approach a local shop to recharge by cash, or ask a local friend to help.